# Path from JFileChooser in Java Format

Tags: java, swing, path, jfilechooser

How to make a JFileChooser return the file path in the format, that Java could open the file?

.getPath() returns the path with \ (on Windows), but I want it to return the path with /
Is this possible?

Greeting Ra1ningSn0w

Comment: Think Java can use "\" on Windows to open files too.

Comment: No... - it seems to don't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `getSelectedFile()` of `JFileChooser` will return a `File` object that is enough to open a file. If you don't want this file to open, but only to return its path, you can call `File`'s method `getAbsolutePath()`. It will return a file path in form dependent on operating system.

To get the path use (`fc` is `JFileChooser` object):

```
String path = fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath().replace('\\', '/');
```

Comment: I don't want a File to be returned and getAbsolutePath() returns the path with \ instead of /

Comment: You can always do something like that: `fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath().replace('\', '/');`

Comment: My mistake. Should be `.replace('\\', '/')`

Comment: But '\\' searchs for \\ not \. Does not work, too. Already tested it. Edit: It works, thanks - my misktake :P